# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency for empty array dependency

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am getting missing dependency warning.

*`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchFeatured'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`*

**My Code**

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchFeatured = () => {
            onSnapshot(faeturedCollectionRef, (snapshot) =>
                setFeatured(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
            )
        }
        fetchFeatured();
    }, [])
```

I have used empty array for avoiding loop.

Comment: Go through this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook and see if it helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main purpose of the this warning is to prevent the developers from missing dependencies inside their effect and lost some behavior or unintended effect. In this case, you can

1. Just ignore it.
2. Suppress that rule for the entire project: Go to `.eslintrc` file and change `'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'warn'` to `'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'off'`
3. Supress the rule only in this instance:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFeatured = () => {
        onSnapshot(faeturedCollectionRef, (snapshot) =>
            setFeatured(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
            )
        }
        fetchFeatured();
// eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can avoid the waring by disabling it with a comment like this

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFeatured = () => {
        onSnapshot(faeturedCollectionRef, (snapshot) =>
            setFeatured(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
        )
    }
    fetchFeatured();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [])
```